# Metodos en Django se llaman al recargar

Tags: python, django

Tengo una función dentro del modelo de Django que aumenta el campo a +1

```
    def birthday(self):
      self.age +=1
      self.save()
```

Lo llamo en la plantilla a través de un button onclick

```
<button type="submit" onclick="{{character.birthday}}">Birthday</button>
```

El problema es que cada vez que actualizo la página (f5) me hace esta función, es decir, me aumenta 1 a la edad sin hacer clic.

También puse en su momento la función en la vista pero me sucedía lo mismo, como puedo hacer para que el método solo sea llamada cuando hago clic en el botón y no cuando recargo? Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Lo que esta pasando es que cuando django renderiza esto `{{character.birthday}}` ejecuta el metodo directamente, no tiene en cuenta si esta adentro de un onclick.

Para arreglarlo hacé una view que reciba el id del modelo character y que aumente el numero por db y lo guarde.

por ejemplo:

```
Character.objects.filter(id=id_que_viene_por_parametro).update(age=F("age") + 1)
```

luego en el template en el onclick mandas un POST por jquery o un GET con el id del Character, por ejemplo asi por POST:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#id_del_button").submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/url/",
      data: {
        id_que_viene_por_parametro: "{{ id }}",
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
      },
      success: function () {
        ...
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

hacer lo que estas haciendo:

```
def birthday(self):
      self.age +=1
      self.save()
```

no te lo recomiendo porque si alguien mas lo actualiza en el mismo momento, te va a tirar un numero erroneo y no va a sumar bien porque lo guarda en memoria antes y luego con el numero desactualizado lo vuelve a guardar. Hay como una condicion de carrera que te lo podes ahorrar con la F function.